# Android Square Register API: NO_NETWORK - Square Register could not connect to the internet

Tags: android, square-connect

When using the Square Register app manually and the device is offline, I am able to enter transactions fine. (They appear to be queued and sent to the server when the device comes back online.)

But when I start the Square Register app from my activity and the device is offline, the operation fails:

> NO_NETWORK - Square Register could not connect to the internet.

This seems like an inconsistency. Is there any way around it so I can still use the API (to take card payments via a Square card reader attached to my device) when my device is offline?

Comment: You should be able to process offline but some API requests would fail. Could you share more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need an internet connection to verify that the specified client_id is allowed to use Register API and that the merchant has authorized the app. After that the information is cached to enable offline mode. Hope that helps!